# Equivalent of #ifdef syntax in protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers

What is the #ifdef equivalent in protobuf messages? I don't find anything in language guide https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto

Answer (score 10):

There is none built into the Protobuf language itself, but you could of course run the C preprocessor over your `.proto` files before passing them to `protoc`. On Unix systems:

```
cpp -P src.proto > preprocessed.proto
protoc preprocessed.proto
```

`cpp` (which comes with your C compiler) will evaluate `#ifdef` and other C preprocessor directives (anything starting with `#`) and output a new file with the results.

(The `-P` option prevents the preprocessor from outputting debug info directives intended for the C compiler, which `protoc` wouldn't understand.)